# Detecting if Sprite has passed "imaginary" line

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So far, I have created a function that spawns a ball and launches it  based on an impulse. my goal is to later launch it in random positions, however, for now, I want to just have that launch point be somewhere on the screen I set, my function is as follows,

```
 func SpawnBall() {
        let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Soccer")
        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture:ball.texture!,size:ball.texture!.size())
       ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
        ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    //    ball.position = CGPoint(x: -150, y: 320)
        self.addChild(ball)
        ball.position = CGPoint(x: -150, y: 320)
        ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 500, dy: 1000))
        ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = netCategory
        ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BallCategory
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
        self.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
        self.physicsBody?.friction = 0
}
```

....

The problem I have however, is I want to know if the ball has passed a certain line or imaginary line. So I was just check ball.position.x, but for some reason this does not update, I know I have set it in the function, but why does the position not update when the impulse is applied?

Comment: how are you checking the balls position?  my guess is the ball you are checking is not the ball on the scene, but a secret ghost ball.

Comment: I use a simple if statement.  if (ball.position.x > 240 ) { print("passed") }

Comment: ... read my comment completely

Comment: I did and I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that.

Comment: I mean exactly what i said.  The variable you are checking is not the ball you have on the screen.  You created another ball, but this new ball is not on the scene.

Comment: Okay, I call this function once, and I'm kind of new to this, so why would this ball not be the one on the scene? Doesn't the addchild add it to the scene? Would an SKAction be better?

Comment: It adds the local ball to the scene, apparently you have a global one somewhere

Comment: The code you posted adds the balls to the scene. At some point, when checking the position of the balls, you need to loop over them. How are you doing that? I suggest you post that code.